# Image Edge Preserving Smoothing

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, smoothing, edge-preserving-filter

I'm searching for a method that can smooth a 3D volume whilst preserving the edges in my volume.

I researched anisotropic diffusion filtering and bilateral filtering, but I'm having trouble to evaluate if they can be efficiently used on +30M voxels volumes.

So I need:

- Relatively fast algorithm even with 512x512x200 volumes
- Good edge preserving properties
- Any help to understand those methods.

Comment: Most edge-preserving smoothing algorithms are based around [minimizing total variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising) of the signal. I think it should work for 3D signal as well. Perhaps a good place to start looking.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot do it volume-piece wise?

Comment: @Phonon seems a good for what I want to do. I found few hours after I asked this question, an article in the book _Multi Modality State-of-the-Art Medical Image Segmentation and Registration Methodologies: Volume 1_ a methodology with goals very similar to mine and they used a 3D anisotropic diffusion filter. I'm going to try that for the moment but i'll definitely check on your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @user4619 what do you mean?

Comment: I mean break down the volume into smaller volumes, and filter those separately, if processing power is an issue.

Comment: @user4619 ah yeah it could be a solution. I'm going to test things with a 3D anisotropic filter. If it's not fast enough I'll think about parallel execution and changing my algorithm.

Comment: @SilouaneGerin, Could you please review my answer? If it answers your question, please mark it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the Bilateral Filter then you can use the Guided Filter.
The nice property of the Guided Filter is its low complexity.
There is a simple and efficient implementation with with linear complexity of the number of pixels.

You may also have a look at:

- [Fast Anisotropic Curvature Preserving Smoothing](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Fast-Anisotropic-Curvature-Preserving-Smoothing).
- [Simple Image Edge Preserving Filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74674/simple-image-edge-preserving-filter?noredirect=1&lq=1).